# Erro ocasional ao transmitir NFCe nos novos webservices da Sefaz do RS - Connection

Tags: java, nfe

Tenho um sistema de emissão de NFe e NFCe que usamos para vários clientes do RS. Há alguns meses a sefaz daqui andou mudando a estrutura dos webservices, então eles também disponibilizaram novas URL's para acesso ao serviço (as antigas continuam funcionando até final de 2015). Já baixei a cadeia de certificados e importei em nosso repositório de certificados confiáveis. Fiz alguns testes e tive o seguinte problema: As vezes funciona e as vezes não! As vezes eu mando 5 notas e todas são emitidas sem problema nenhum, e do nada começa a dar erro ao conectar ao WS. O erro que acontece (quando acontece) é o seguinte:

```
INFO (11:19:42,368) - Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://nfce-homologacao.sefazrs.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeAutorizacao/NFeAutorizacao.asmx]
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Achei que pudesse ser algo no meu provedor de internet, porém tentei colocar em alguns clientes e ocorre o mesmo problema. As vezes da certo e em outras da esse erro.

Com a URL antiga funcionava tudo 100%, isso era quando a URL antiga servia tanto pra NFe quanto pra NFCe. Agora com as novas eles separaram os serviços, e a nova da NFe funciona perfeitamente, o problema está apenas na NFCe.

Falei com o pessoal da sefaz e segundo eles não é problema com eles. Porém, não souberam informar o por que de as vezes a conexão não ser aceita. Também acredito não ser problema em meu código, visto que as vezes funciona. Mas aí já não posso ter tanta certeza. Alguém sabe o que poderia estar acontecendo?

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema. Você conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Resolvi sim. Ontem aconteceu o problema na NFe/CTe/MDFe também, a solução postei como resposta pra minha pergunta, da uma olhada aí e comenta se não servir pro seu caso.

Comment: Alerta de desabafo adiante: felizes dos que moram fora de SP, que não estão sujeitos a comprar o tal SAT com preço tabelado para fazer NFC-e (sai o lobby das impressoras fiscais, entra o lobby do SAT para uma meia duzia de fabricantes encherem o bolso de grana na marra).Acho muito legal o SAT, desde que OPCIONAL.... (pra quem não sabe o que é, é um hardware que você é obrigado a adquirir por uns 1300 reais pra poder emitir NFC-e em SP)

Comment: Esse é o governo que nós temos... daqui a alguns meses eles suspendem o sat e dão um jeito de fazer mais alguma burocracia absurda que vai sobrar pro contribuinte pagar, e assim segue o baile...

Comment: Eu também utilizo ele dinâmico, e resolvi dessa maneira. Só não entendo, pq na versão 7 do java, ele não dá erro. Apenas na versão 8. Resolvi no mesmo dia da pergunta hahaha. De qualquer forma, valeu buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido.
Estava usando uma classe chamada `SocketFactoryDinamico`, que era um socket personalizado, para fazer a comunicação com os serviços da SEFAZ.
Acontece que nesta classe, havia um parâmetro que dizia qual era o protocolo de segurança na comunicação, que quando dava erro era TLS. Mudando para TLSv1 resolveu o problema:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
```

Esse problema acontecia ha alguns meses para a NFCe no Rio Grande do Sul. Ontem, dia 05/11/2015, também passou a ocorrer para todos os demais serviços da SEFAZ (NFe/CTe/MDFe, etc). A mesma correção se aplica a todos esses serviços para quem também usa Socket dinamico/personalizado na conexão.

**Atualização**

Realmente o erro só passou a acontecer a partir do java 8, então se alguém quiser uma solução temporária para o problema enquanto não ajusta na programação conforme eu postei acima, instale o java 7.